# Twisted package from Lucid to Karmic

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-10.04, twisted

Can I install the "Twisted" package from Lucid onto Karmic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actual lucid package or the app twisted - if the second bit yes:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/twisted